# Configuring multiple management ports (HP/Aruba)

Tags: hp-procurve, management, aruba

The HP Aruba 5412Rzl2 and has two management modules on it. They work active/passive from what i can tell. I would like to assign (a static) IP address to their management ports (in case I need it some day). There are two management ports (one on each module).

I've found the commands on how to give oobm IP. But there is only one IP i am able to assign which probably is for the primary management module.

Two questions:

1. Do you assign IPs to each management port separately? If so how? I can only access oobm as general - not module (primary/secondary) based.
2. Can I give the management (oobm) IP exactly the same as another IP I have assigned for in-bound network, like one of my vlan ip interface IP addresses? (for example 192.168.10.10/24 for both vlan123 interface (inter-vlan) ip and for the management port (oobm) IP.) Their gateway addresses will be the same too.

Thanks in advance!

PS: There won't be a direct cable connected from the management port to another (sw) physical port. I intend to directly connect only if i get locked out or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the 5400R zl2 series, the front management ports are for dedicated out-of-band management (OOBM). You can connect them to a dedicated management network - if you have one - or use them locally in case of emergency, just like the serial console ports.

Connecting those port to another switch port doesn't make too much sense. Without a dedicated management network, users just use in-band management, via a configured management VLAN (`management-vlan VLANID`). Note that a management VLAN doesn't participate in L3 switching and needs to be routed elsewhere (ie. on your firewall).

Without a specific management VLAN, any switch IP address can be used for management (unless you use OOBM).

You configure the oobm ports by using `oobm ip address [dhcp-bootp | ip-address/mask-length]`. There's only one IP configuration for both ports with redundant management modules. Of course, you should use a unique address and not re-use an already existing address - while overlapping addressing may be possible on certain hardware, it's generally not advisable.

See

https://www.arubanetworks.com/techdocs/AOS-S/16.11/MCG/KB/content/3810m-5400r.htm

https://www.arubanetworks.com/techdocs/AOS-Switch/16.11/Aruba%203810%265400R%20Advanced%20Traffic%20Management%20Guide%20for%20AOS-S%2016.11.pdf

and

https://www.arubanetworks.com/techdocs/AOS-S/16.11/ATMG/KB/content/home_kb.htm

https://www.arubanetworks.com/techdocs/AOS-Switch/16.11/Aruba%203810%265400R%20Advanced%20Traffic%20Management%20Guide%20for%20AOS-S%2016.11.pdf

for further details.

Comment: At first I didn't want to test it since the system is part of production. But I had to due to the second part of your answer not feeling right: "Of course, you need a unique address and cannot re-use an already existing address.". This (mgmt port) is part of oob network. The ip address should not conflict with an address from in-bound. I tested it (configured my oobm ip and inbound svi ip identical) and that seems to be the case. If you could edit/update your reply I will accept it as an answer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I further investigated this point and found different results for different vendors. Arista management port for example does not allow its ip to be the same as an inbound one. I assume this is the case for Cisco too. HP/Aruba on the other hand does. Since the original question was regarding HP/Aruba (5412Rzl2 to be exact) the answer still should be more clear. If @Zac67 can update his answer I will accept.

Comment: Yes, this may be vastly different between vendors or even product lines. As it is, the answer is only valid for the 5400R zl2 series.

Comment: But 5400R zl2 doesn't require a unique ip between oob and inbound. Your answer makes it sound as it does. That part should be edited to say "it's a general rule of thumb" or that "vendors can act differently in that regard". Don't get me wrong; I'm only asking for an edit/update so future queries regarding this matter will get a more precise answer. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: OK, if you've tested so (couldn't find a definite answer in HPE docs) - but I'd seriously advise against an overlapping management network.